# Drawing zig-zag lines is much slower than drawing straight lines

Tags: c#, gdi+

While using a self-written graphing control I noticed that the painting of the graph was much slower while displaying noisy data than when it displayed clean data.
I dug further into and narrowed the problem down to its bare minimum difference: Drawing the same amount of lines with varying Y values versus drawing lines with the same Y value.

So for example I put together the following tests. I generate lists of points, one with random Y values, one with the same Y, and one with a Zig-Zag Y pattern.

```
private List<PointF> GenerateRandom(int n, int width, int height)
{
    //Generate random pattern
    Random rnd = new Random();
    float stepwidth = Convert.ToSingle(width / n);
    float mid = Convert.ToSingle(height / 2);
    float lastx = 0;
    float lasty = mid;
    List<PointF> res = new List<PointF>();
    res.Add(new PointF(lastx, lasty));
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        var x = stepwidth * i;
        var y = Convert.ToSingle(height * rnd.NextDouble());
        res.Add(new PointF(x, y));
    }
    return res;
}
private List<PointF> GenerateUnity(int n, int width, int height)
{
    //Generate points along a simple line
    float stepwidth = Convert.ToSingle(width / n);
    float mid = Convert.ToSingle(height / 2);
    float lastx = 0;
    float lasty = mid;
    List<PointF> res = new List<PointF>();
    res.Add(new PointF(lastx, lasty));
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        var x = stepwidth * i;
        var y = mid;
        res.Add(new PointF(x, y));
    }
    return res;
}
private List<PointF> GenerateZigZag(int n, int width, int height)
{
    //Generate an Up/Down List
    float stepwidth = Convert.ToSingle(width / n);
    float mid = Convert.ToSingle(height / 2);
    float lastx = 0;
    float lasty = mid;
    List<PointF> res = new List<PointF>();
    res.Add(new PointF(lastx, lasty));
    var state = false;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        var x = stepwidth * i;
        var y = mid - (state ? 50 : -50);
        res.Add(new PointF(x, y));
        state = !state;
    }
    return res;
}
```

I now draw each list of points a few times and compare how long it takes:

```
private void DoTheTest()
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(970, 512);
    var random = GenerateRandom(2500, bmp.Width, bmp.Height).ToArray();
    var unity = GenerateUnity(2500, bmp.Width, bmp.Height).ToArray();
    var ZigZag = GenerateZigZag(2500, bmp.Width, bmp.Height).ToArray();

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        var tUnity = BenchmarkDraw(g, 200, unity);
        var tRandom = BenchmarkDraw(g, 200, random);
        var tZigZag = BenchmarkDraw(g, 200, ZigZag);
        MessageBox.Show(tUnity.ToString() + "\r\n" + tRandom.ToString() + "\r\n" + tZigZag.ToString());
    }
}
private double BenchmarkDraw(Graphics g, int n, PointF[] Points)
{
    var Times = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        System.DateTime d3 = DateTime.Now;
        DrawLines(g, Points);
        System.DateTime d4 = DateTime.Now;
        Times.Add((d4 - d3).TotalMilliseconds);
    }
    return Times.Average();
}
private void DrawLines(Graphics g, PointF[] Points)
{
    g.DrawLines(Pens.Black, Points);
}
```

I come up with the following durations per draw:

```
Straight Line: 0.095 ms
Zig-Zag Pattern: 3.24 ms
Random Pattern: 5.47 ms
```

So it seems to get progressively worse, the more change there is in the lines to be drawn, and that is also a real world effect I encountered in the control painting I mentioned in the beginning.

My questions are thus the following:

1. Why does it make a such a brutal difference, which lines are to be drawn?
2. How can I improve the drawing speed for the noisy data?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that bechmarks always are much harder to get right than wrong: 1) Depending on the y-variations your lines may be a __lot__ longer. You should eliminate this difference from the results. 2) I would be amazed if the straight lines were not faster as this would mean the gdi routines don't recognize them and miss a great chance for optimizing. Even a fast line algorithm must be slower than going straight horizontally/vertically for which you need no algorithm at all, neither for keeping the slope not for anialiasing the steps..

Comment: 3) you may want to test various smoothingmodes. with antaliasing even a slight slope will result in ca 2-3 times as many pixels that must be painted above and below the center line.

Comment: @TaW Damn, I think your first point is correct and even quite obvious now that you point it out. If I divide by average line length, the random and zig-zag times converge. The straight is actually the slowest, but that may just mean some kind of other overhead. So that's the reason, got to think about a way around it if there is one. But optimizing line drawing is another question. Would you add an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three reasons come to mind:

- **Line Length** : Depending on the actual numbers sloped lines may be longer by just a few pixels or a lot or even by some substantial factor. Looking at your code I suspect the latter..
- **Algorithm** : Drawing sloped lines does take some algorithm to find the next pixels. Even fast drawing routines need to do some computations as opposed to vertical or horizontal lines, which run straight through the pixel arrays.
- **Anti-Aliasing** : Unless you turn off anti-aliasing completely (with all the ugly consequences) the number of pixels to paint will also be around 2-3 times more as all those anti-aliasing pixels above and below the center lines must also be calculated and drawn. Not to forget calculating their colors!

The remedy for the latter part is obviously to turn off anti-aliasing, but the other problems are simply the way things are.  So best don't worry and be happy about the speedy straight lines :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a lot of lines or your lines could be very long (a few time the size of the screen), or if you have a lot of almost 0 pixel line, you have to wrote code to reduce useless drawing of lines.

Well, here are some ideas:

- If you write many lines at the same x, then you could replace those by a single line between min and max y at that x.
- If your line goes way beyond the screen boundary, you should clip them.
- If a line is completly outside of the visible area, you should skip it.
- If a line have a 0 length, you should not write it.
- If a line has a single pixel length, you should write only that pixel.

Obviously, the benefit depends a lot on how many lines you draw... And also the alternative might not give the exact same result...

In practice, it you draw a chart on a screen, then if you display only useful information, it should be pretty fast on modern hardware.

Well if you use style or colors, it might not be as trivial to optimize the displaying of the data.

Alternatively, they are some charting component that are optimized for display large data... The good one are generally expensive but it might still worth it. Often trials are available so you can get a good idea on how much you might increase the performance and then decide what to do.

Comment: Thank you for your input, phil. You make good points about optimizing the drawing process to reduce not required drawing operations. I'll look into it. In most cases it is fine, since my component isn't used for real-time data. Lately I used it with digital readouts and noticed the extreme slowdown during noisy periods, that's what seemed odd to me. The chart is usually optimized for other things with some weird custom features ;)